# Xcode 8 forces to 'Choose an initial device view'

Tags: ios10, xcode8

[image]

I currently updated to Xcode 8 GM.
When I try to see my storyboard, above window pops up and there's no way to avoid this settings.
I chose 6s screen and all my view controllers changed to 6s size.
It will be much harder to adjust layout constraints on that small screens.
I believe it's possible to change the size to iPad but I want to know what this is first.

No way to comeback to ambiguous sized view controllers?

What is this settings for?

Comment: Same here, my storyboards changed to iPhone 6s and all of my autolayout constraints are messed up, 36 constraint warnings, why? @ Vincent Gigandet - Did you get any constraint warnings when you selected the iPhone 6s as the device view?

Comment: @fs_tigre - Me too but not that many. I found two buttons are missing which freaks me out so I came back to xcode 7. I will not use xcode 8 until I find a clear solution.

Comment: I have been playing around with with XCode 8 and it looks like this is the new way to work with auto layout in XCode 8, the wAny-hAny option it's gone. I think this is actually an improvement since now it is faster to change to different devices. There is no way to avoid the pop-up box you are talking about.

Comment: I have many xib files, it seems like I have to choose device and adjust auto layout constraint for every file. I am going to be crazy!

Comment: @huuang - I am using xib's as well.  Have you found a good solution for this issue?  If I choose the iPhone SE and then run my app on an iPhone 6, I don't see any warnings, but my views are all sized down as if I were running an SE simulator inside my iPhone 6...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **Xcode 8.1 updated version**, there is a **shortcut** button for this.

For cases, when only updating of the Xcode fired these warnings, just select the problematic view's superview (containing mentioned constraints), and click this **update frames** button:

[image]

Answer (score 17):

A way "come back to ambiguous sized" can be:

Select all the Scenes(View Controllers) in the Storyboard, show the Size inspector, change the Simulated Size to Freeform, then set Width Height = 600.

Then, those tons of warnings disappear.

[image]

Comment: going with this solution for now, but i am afraid this may cause IB issues or display issues down the road while going from 'inferred' to 'freeform',  hopefully i won't have to come back and update this post with any issues, + 1 for now : )

Answer (score 9):

1. Select warning in the Scenes (View Controllers)
2. Select 'Update Frames'
3. Check 'apply to all views in the container'
4. Select 'Fix Misplacement'

[image]

Or

1. Select View in the Scenes (View Controllers) in the Storyboard
2. Select 'Resolve Auto Layout Issues'
3. Select 'All Views -> Update Frames'

[image]

Then, those warnings disappear.

Answer (score 5):

Its easy to do in XCode 8.1
pedrouan answer is perfect. I am just adding the same answer in pictorial representation.

I just opened up my xib file of complex cell and its a lot of warnings; You can see in following picture:
[image]

You just need to select top level view/cell in xib hierarchy and click 'Update Frames' button; Everything will become perfect.
[image]
All warnings will gone like following screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot!